# Java BeanUtilsBean : Convert Date to String

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying to run `BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().populate(...)` but on the HTML form, there is a field that carries String representation of Date of Birth. The object bean has the field type of `java.util.Date`

Read some search from Ggl that have to build custom converters but not quite understand how to do that.

Anyone can help?

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String[]> formData = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    formData.put("email", new String[]{"danny@gmail.com"});
    formData.put("firstName", new String[]{"danny"});
    formData.put("lastName", new String[]{"miller"});
    formData.put("dob", new String[]{"15-Apr-1980"});
    formData.put("userName", new String[]{"dannymiller"});
    try {
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
        DateTimeConverter dtConverter = new DateConverter();
        dtConverter.setPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy");

        ConvertUtilsBean convertUtilsBean = new ConvertUtilsBean();
        convertUtilsBean.deregister(Date.class);
        convertUtilsBean.register(dtConverter, Date.class);

        BeanUtilsBean beanUtilsBean = new BeanUtilsBean(convertUtilsBean, new PropertyUtilsBean());

        beanUtilsBean.populate(consumer, formData);


        if (consumer != null) {
            System.out.println(consumer.getEmail());
            System.out.println(consumer.getFirstName());
            System.out.println(consumer.getLastName());
            System.out.println(consumer.getDob());
            System.out.println(consumer.getUserName());
        }
    } catch  (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The return error:

> Apr 22, 2011 11:14:45 PM
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.DateTimeConverter
>   toDate WARNING:     DateConverter does
>   not support default String to 'Date'
>   conversion. Apr 22, 2011 11:14:45 PM
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.DateTimeConverter
>   toDate WARNING:     (N.B. Re-configure
>   Converter or use alternative
>   implementation) Exception in thread
>   "main"
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException:
>   DateConverter does not support default
>   String to 'Date' conversion.  at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.DateTimeConverter.toDate(DateTimeConverter.java:468)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.DateTimeConverter.convertToType(DateTimeConverter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.convert(AbstractConverter.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.ConverterFacade.convert(ConverterFacade.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.convert(ConvertUtilsBean.java:470)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1008)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:830)
>     at
>   com.ymatch.test.BeanTest.main(BeanTest.java:32)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done using this method:

```
public Object populate(Object obj, HashMap<String, String[]> formData)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        ConvertUtils
                .register(new StringToDateConverter(), java.util.Date.class);
        BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().populate(obj, formData);
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: i have a question, if value of date is null send exception. How can solve? thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You need a `SimpleDateFormat` by which to parse the given string according to a specified format. For that you'd need to handle the conversion manually - name the request parameter differently and then set it manually.

But beanutils has a conversion utility, so you can use it instead (this code can be executed once per application):

```
DateTimeConverter dtConverter = new DateConverter();
dtConverter.setPattern("<your custom date pattern here>");
ConvertUtils.register(dtConverter, Date.class);
```

Comment: I just uploaded the codes, which part I should put in SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: very funny, `DateTimeConverter dtConverter = new DateTimeConverter();`
is not possible to be instantiated.

Comment: sorry, see updated. it's `DateConverter` that's the concrete class

Comment: Sorry mate, I had updated the code like above but it still the same error.