# Getting error when using BeanUtils.copyProperties(dest, src)

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I have 2 form Classes

```
public class Form1{
 int id,
 String name,
 DateTime lastModified;

 //setters and getters
 }


public class Form2 {
 int id,
 String name,
 Date lastModified;

 //setters and getters
 }
```

ie., one of the form has the same variable name lastModified with Date type and other one with joda DateTime type

I am trying to copy form1 values to form2

```
Form1 form1 = dao.getForm1();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();

BeanUtils.copyProperties(form2,form1)
```

But it is giving me error like

```
 org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: DateConverter does not        support default String to 'Date' conversion.
```

I tried the solution given in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5757379/1370555

But it is giving me error like

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: Error converting 'org.joda.time.DateTime' to 'Date' using pattern 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.0 Z'
```

I think it can be solved with apache ConvertUtils but i am not getting exactly how it is to be done

Can any one help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`BeanUtils.copyProperties(form2,form1)` copies the property values of one form to another form.Since your both forms have `lastModified` property with different data types and `org.joda.time.DateTime` is not compatible with `java.util.Date` , you are getting the exception.

You can change the property to same reference types or have a constructor which will assign the value to a matching data type of a same variable reference

Comment: The requirement is such that one form has variable of type Date and other DateTime.